# Can't Display Table Headers in Responsive table layout

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Am using below mentioned code to display table in WordPress post. It displayed table correctly, but I want to make to responsive so, I used custom CSS code to make Responsive table layout. It's working but missing table headers while resizing page layout. can anyone please guide me.

```
$menu .= '<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>';
                while ( have_rows('sections_items') ) : the_row();
                        // Your loop code
                        $menu .= '<tr><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_names').'</td><td>'.get_sub_field('dish_description').'</td><td>$ '.get_sub_field('dish_price').'</td></tr>';
                    endwhile;
                $menu .= '</table> ';
```

/* CSS code*/

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}
table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}
table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}
table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

/* end of css*/ Here is the out of table am getting

[image: http://imgur.com/a/GBW5f]

Comment: Is `<thead>` shown in the generated source code ?

Comment: am using ACF to display table in WordPress. but I want to add CSS to make table responsive. but missing table headers

Comment: Maybe you are missing `<th scope="col">` and `<td data-label="thead name">`

Comment: What's the logic behind making `thead { width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; }`?

Comment: still not getting table headers.

Comment: some asked same question Great solution! However, I was wondering why you used:

border: none;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px;

for the <thead> instead of just display:none; ?   but admin replied Great question, Nico. The reason is for accessibility. If I use `display: none` the <thead> won't render at all. And we want assistive technology to read the <thead>. Using this rule, the <thead> does render fully, it's just not presented on the page.

Comment: even `<tbody>` is missing

Comment: i tried <tbody> also

Comment: Provide a fiddle with the generated html and css

Comment: need to add any <th> in @media?

Comment: no correct answer till now. please help me. working on this code from last one month

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code successfully hides the existing thead / th tags and swaps the tr and td tags from rows to columns and vice versa, clever. Perhaps you could use :before in the CSS to re-add the header info before the respective td tags in each table. I added the following to the end of the CSS (before the last 2 squiggly brackets:

```
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Description"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Price"; }
```

I think you can change the contents of these from the Javascript also, if coding it into the CSS isn't acceptable.

Here's the JSfiddle: [using :before](https://jsfiddle.net/j38gk0tm/)